# HTML5 video player: dynamically loading videos

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to know how to make the player play a video dynamically 
for example: http://video.com/viewer.php?file=123.flv
where 123.flv will be played
i am working with jwpayer

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("test").setup({
    file:"a.mp3",
hieght:360,


    modes:[
        { type:'html5' }
    ]


});
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work with your original code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("test").setup({
    file:"<?php echo htmlentities($_GET['file']); ?>",
    hieght:360,


    modes:[
        { type:'html5' }
    ]


});
```